# How to use MySQLDataAdapter to load table content in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataadapter

I've found some solutions on stackoverflow and other sites like this (assume the connection is already opened):

```
sc.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from  mydatabase.mytable;", sc);
adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

adapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
sc.Close();
```

but it's not working propoerly. All I get is an empty datagridview which let's me assume that the data is not loaded.

When I first loaded the data to a list - list myList with MySQLDataReader, I could load the data normally to the datagridview with the following code:

```
foreach (myClass a in myList)
{
     this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(a.Id, a.2ndColumn, a.3rdCoulmn, and so on..;
}
```

Can you please tell me why I couldn't load the datatable with the MySQLAdapter? Some of the asnwers I checked showed I should be able to load it and display it this way..

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this](http://ycouriel.blogspot.nl/2009/10/c-datagridview-and-mysql.html) link, I've used it a while ago and it worked fine for me.
Also, the `for` loop you have isn't needed, when linking an collection to the `DataSource` property it should automatically update the GridView.